# Como adicionar as permissões necessárias para o Printer Job funcionar no Tomcat7

Tags: java, java-ee, tomcat

**Ambiente**

Meu ambiente é Tomcat7 e estou usando Java 1.8, Windows 10 e estou usando um PDF Reader para testar a impressão. Meu usuário é administrador da máquina.

**Problema**

Estou tentando enviar um PDF para impressão, porém esse PDF não é impresso. Quando o pedido de impressão chega na fila, o mesmo fica em estado spooling eternamente com tamanho em branco.

A impressão funciona se eu iniciar o Tomcat7 pelo CMD, caso eu use o services.msc ou o TomcatW a impressão não funciona. A diferença entre os dois é a inicialização do perfil de usuário no log do CMD o Tomcat7 carrega **C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile.dnx\bin** e no log usando o services.msc **C:\Users\MY_USER.dnx\bin**

Eu descobri que isso significa problemas de permissão para a fila de impressão, porém não consigo encontrar um motivo específico para que meu usuário que é administrador da máquina não possa imprimir. Coisas que eu já tentei para resolver o problema:

1. Executar o Tomcat7 utilizando a opção de LogOn com uma conta de Administrador (Inclusive administrador da rede)
2. Habilitar a opção "Allow service to interact with desktop"
3. Desabilitar Firewall/ AntiVirus
4. Iniciar o Tomcat7w com privilégios de administrador para todos os usuários.
5. Adicionar o usuário da máquina no 'Log on as service' utilizando o gpedit
6. Trocar a versão do Java para 7.
7. Instalar/ Desinstalar o serviço do tomcat utilizando um usuário com privilégios de Administrador.
8. Limpar a chave de registro (HKEY) do Tomcat7

Eu já procurei no [SO em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17390207/printing-is-not-working-in-tomcat-when-i-start-server-with-services-mscfrom-cl) inclusive e pela web, nenhuma das soluções encontradas funcionou.

Código que estou usando para impressão:
Usando o PDFBox para carregar o PDF.

```
PDDocument pdDoc = PDDocument.load(pdfFile);

PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
job.setPrintService(service);
job.setJobName("The System Job");
job.setPageable(new PDFPageable(pdDoc));
job.print();

pdDoc.close();
```

Eu encontrei uma solução utilizando o PrintService para criar o PrinterJob e mesmo assim não funcionou.

```
service.createPrintJob().print(pdDoc, null);
```

Alguém tem alguma solução para o problema?